# Validate iso datetime of csv column pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, autoload

The dateformats that I'm expecting is as such:

`"2023-01-01T09:00:00.0000000+03:00"`

When reading `csv` files with `pyspark`, how can I validate for the correctness of this field in a robust way? I want to ensure that the timestamp column of my `csv`s have the correct format.

Comment: I think your question is missing some info

Comment: @JNevill I added the missing info. Thanx.